# how to apply bootstrap modal click event in a span?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

But how can i add modal click event in a span like a tag?

```
<a href="#Popup" class="" data-toggle="modal">Click here</a>
```

Comment: got solution <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Popup">hi</span>

Answer (score 3):

Something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/3n9cs079/)**??

```
<span class="spmodal" data-target="#Popup" data-toggle="modal">Click here</span>
```

Comment: My only suggestion for this would be to apply some styling to the span (cursor: pointer;).

Answer (score 2):

Well gotta try this

```
<span class="yourClass" data-target="#Popup" data-toggle="modal">Click here</span>
```